# Python Selenium get all urls extensions on a webpage as a list

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to get a list of all the text related to the URL. in the webpage
The code in the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> gives me this:

```html
<sr-cell-name name="Otto Kraf" url="/ark:/61903/1:1:Q247-6VCC" relationship="Principal" collection-name="New York, New York City, Police Census, 1890"></sr-cell-name>
```

There is a list of 20 names such as Otto Kraf on the page, and I want to make a list of the URLs that relate to each name.

I tried `driver_get_element_by(xpath, name, css_selecter, and xpath)` but none seem to find the URL.

Snapshot of the HTML:

[updated html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Bf4G.jpg)

[nested shadow roots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFlhD.jpg)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NB0M.jpg)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! I don't have knowledge about the area you're asking about, but I would recommend, if you can, copy/pasting your code into a code block instead of linking a screenshot. This may increase the chance of people responding.

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of all the *urls* within the webpage in the webpage using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491)  you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("url") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.table.table-element-table span.td[name='name'] sr-cell-name[name][url]")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("url") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='table table-element-table']//span[@class='td' and @name='name']//sr-cell-name[@name and @url]")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Update

The elements seems to be within **`#shadow-root (open)`**. You can find a couple of relevant discussions on how to access the elements within *#shadow-root (open)* in:

- [Selenium - Send keys to input password in a shadow-root (open) and multiple iframes for Norwegian BankId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59231027/selenium-send-keys-to-input-password-in-a-shadow-root-open-and-multiple-ifra/59249823#59249823)
- [How to automate shadow DOM elements using selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55761810/how-to-automate-shadow-dom-elements-using-selenium/55763793#55763793)
- [How to interact with the elements within #shadow-root (open) while Clearing Browsing Data of Chrome Browser using cssSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380091/how-to-interact-with-the-elements-within-shadow-root-open-while-clearing-brow)

Comment: Thank you for your help, however, when I run the code, I receive the error that I updated in my post. This may be because of the nested shadow roots that I had to go through, and I updated the html code and my code to show how I dealt with the shadow roots. Thank you again.

Comment: @JaredWillamson Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am able to access the shadow root where the urls are located, I can even find the class table.table-element-table which they are under. I use shadow_root4.find_element_by.... and am able to find elements within the shadow root where the urls are located. Is there anyway to modify your code in your original answer using my shadow_root4. to make a list of the urls?