# How to wait for a page finish render and get complated page source

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium

I used Selenium(version 4.1.0) in a C# project.I looked up a lot of information.
This is My code

```
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("xxxx");
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("xxx")));
context.Response.Write(driver.pageSource);
```

This is very effective for get full page html until I test https://jp.mercari.com.
It can not get full page.

Is there any other way to get the complated page source?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't getting the get full page html as a lot of the elements are distributed within multiple [**#shadow-root (open)**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59249823/7429447) elements.

[image: mercari]

---

### Conclusion

Even after the webpage compltes rendering the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp), the entire [pageSource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53006894/7429447) may not be available. To access the entire [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) you have to use [Document.querySelector()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70198069/7429447).

Comment: I used document.querySelector get the IWebelement ,i can get the text ,but can't get html code by GetAttribute("innerHTML") ,why?